# Monthly count table

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssms

I need to take a monthly count of data in SSMS and visualize it in Power BI. Every month the query to run and add a row to the output table with that months name and the count. So for the MoM, the previous month’s snapshot would be bucketed and saved for comparison with the next month’s snapshot – and so on.  The Week over week would be broken down from the MoM data.  The SQL query will include a count statement and where clauses. What else is needed in the query to get the desired results?

Edit to add info:

My first query would look like this -
select count(id) as id_count, format(getdate(), 'MMM') as Month
into #ABCS_idcount
from HelpDesk_;

If doing this manually I would run this the next month -
insert into #abcs_claimcount ([claimid_count], [Month])
select count(claim) as claimid_count, format(getdate(), 'MMM') as Month from HelpDesk;

However I need to kick this off this month and automate it to run the same time each month going forward.
by Dec I would have three rows with different info in each row.

1102    Oct

1272    nov

1752    Dec

Comment: How could we know? You haven't shared any sample data, table definitions, current attempt at the sql, desired results, or any clues at all besides a list of vague requirements. Please include more information so that we can help you write this sql or whatever it is you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

A temp table (tables starting with `#`), are only kept as long as the session used to create them.  In order to keep this data over time, you will need to create a permanent table, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HelpDeskCountSnapshot (
    claimid_count INT NOT NULL,
    SnapshotMonth NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    SnapshotDate DATEIME DEFAULT (GETDATE()) NOT NULL)
```

You can then insert into this table each month.  Construct this SQL statement and add this to a SQL Agent Job, which can run the SQL statement on a schedule.  Ask a database admin to help set that up if you do not have permissions.